# How to use ProgramFilesFolder value in a variable in a wxi file

Tags: wix, wix3.7

In my wxi file, I want to set a variable that has the Program Files directory. I want it to pick the localized value of Program Files.

```
 <?define MyDirectory="!(wix.LocalizedProgramFilesFolder)\MyFiles"?>
```

I have defined LocalizedProgramFilesFolder as:

```
<WixVariable Id="LocalizedProgramFilesFolder" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]"/>
```

However during installation the MyDirectoryis picked as:

```
"[ProgramFilesFolder]\MyFiles".
```

It does not expand ProgramFilesFolder. 
How do I use ProgramFilesFolder value in a variable in my wxi file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you are using a `MyDirectory` variable. As the [WixVariable docs](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_wixvariable.htm) say:

> WiX variables do not persist into the msi/msm/pcp file, so they cannot
>   be used when an MSI file is being installed; it's a WiX-only concept.

Its value is written as text into wherever you use it. So, if you want the value to have properties substituted at install-time, you must use it only in such a context.

Typical usage of ProgramFilesFolder is as a Directory/@Id, which can have a descendant Directory, such as `MyFiles`. Note: a Directory/@Id is also a property so it can be used as such.

```
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyFiles" />
      </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

`INSTALLFOLDER` is used instead of `MyDirectory`. You can use whatever you want but that the default from the project template. It is all caps, which makes it a public property. A public property value can be passed into the installer sequence from the UI or using `msiexec` or other programs, such a bootstrappers.